# Mongo $OR - Exact match is not returned

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a query that I thought would give me results where any licence plates matched any of the search objects but if I search for an exact match that I know is in the database it is not returned, however partial matches are still returned.

In the following code snippet I had thought the first object would be matching on a exact text match as this covers all the properties a document can have for the category.

```
$or: [
                {
                    "p1": req.query.p1,
                    "p2": req.query.p2,
                    "numbers": req.query.numbers,
                    "l1": req.query.l1,
                    "l2": req.query.l2,
                    "l3": req.query.l3,
                    "category": "current_plates"
                },
                {
                    "numbers": req.query.numbers,
                    "l1": req.query.l1,
                    "l2": req.query.l2,
                    "l3": req.query.l3,
                    "category": "current_plates"
                },
                {
                    "p1": req.query.p1,
                    "p2": req.query.p2,
                    "numbers": req.query.numbers,
                    "category": "current_plates"
                },
                {
                    "l1": req.query.l1,
                    "l2": req.query.l2,
                    "l3": req.query.l3,
                    "category": "current_plates"
                }
              ]
```

Sample Document:

```
{
    "_id": "5dc5d7ee0eef0f4ea047b0e6",
    "p1": "A",
    "p2": "K",
    "numbers": "20",
    "l1": "N",
    "l2": "A",
    "l3": "T",
    "price": 699,
    "plate": "AK20NAT",
    "category": "current_plates"
  }
```

The search string is `AD67NAT`, this is broken up into pieces as:

`p1 = A`
`p2 = D`
`numbers = 67`
`l1 = N`
`l2 = A`
`l3 = T`

A current plate consists of "p1, p2, numbers, l1, l2, l3", category and the mongo ID so it looks like an exact match say `AD67NAT` should be returned but it is not and I cant see why.

Comment: *"... I cant see why."* - Neither can we. However if you actually supplied at least one sample document you expected to match as well as the input parameters you are supplying, ***then*** someone might be able to provide some input on to why exactly you do not get your expected result, and how to correct that. Right now, we just cannot see it since your question does not supply those things.

Comment: This data structure and query is confusing.   The `plate` field is "fine"; what is with `p1`, `p2`, etc. etc.?

Comment: Thats the plate broken up so they could be matched on partial selections, `p1` = prefix 1, `p2` = prefix letter 2, numbers is the numeric portion of a licence plate etc What I am trying to do is to match plates that might be similar to what someone searched for, say they searched for `A1 DOG`, I would want to return other matches for `A1`, as well as other matches for `DOG`. The categories are because a prefix style plate looks like `A1 DOG` whereas a new style plate would look like `AA01 DOG`